# How to add an extra URL mapping for an servlet that already mapped in Eclipse IDE 4.2?

Tags: eclipse, jsp, jakarta-ee, web-applications, deployment

I want to add an extra URL mapping to my we application in Eclipse. Since the eclipse IDE not using web.xml as deployment descriptor , I don't know how to do this.

That is , the servlet LogServlet was already mapped as /LogServlet , but I have need to add an extra mapping as /tamil/LogServlet .

Since web.xml not used as deployment descriptor in Eclipse , I don't know how to do this .

Please help me in this issue.

(Project created in Dynamic Web Module 3.0 in Java EE 6[jdk 7] )

2) Please guide me how to create the web.xml file which contains all deployment info on it.( that "Generate deployment descriptor stub" not generating servlet mappings , only welcome pages tags )

Answer (score 0):

Read [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/annotation/WebServlet.html):

> java.lang.String[]    urlPatterns
>             The URL patterns of the servlet

So you simply need

```
@WebServlet(urlPatterns = {"/LogServlet", "/tamil/LogServlet"})
```

That said, given the patterns you want, it seems you're simply confused between relative and absolute paths, and that a single pattern should be sufficient. If you want more help, explain us why you want these two patterns.

Comment: I need an extras mapping because , a jsp file login.jsp in root folder simply post request to /LogServlet , but the same jsp file in tamil folder posting to /tamil/LogServlet instead of /LogServlet.


Thats why I need this .........

Comment: That's what I suspected. You don't need a second mapping for that. You just need the JSP to post to the correct URL: `../LogServlet`, or, using an absolute path and the JSTL, `<c:url value="/LogServlet"/>`, or even simply `${pageContext.request.contextPath}/LogServlet`. Use absolute paths: they work whatever the current URL is.